# Apple wireless keyboard is not working (typing wrong characters) after cleaning

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I recently cleaned my wireless apple keyboard and now am having trouble with it responding, typing wrong characters and broadcasting un-issued commands. I used glass cleaner for cleaning. Is there any hope?

Comment: Did you remove the batteries before cleaning? Did you spray the cleaner directly on the keyboard, or on a rag first? Did you let it sit a bit before using?

Comment: No, I didn't remove the batteries before cleaning. I used liquid glass cleaner for cleaning then rubbed it with soft cloth and I started using it after 1 hour of cleaning and got this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hope is that the contacts dry out & haven't been shorted out by washed-through dirt...
I'd have used a very slightly damp microfibre cloth, far less chance of getting overspill into the electronics.

Presumably it has a battery in it - remove it, then give it a day in a warm dry place, then try again - before subjecting it to further abuse/cleaning...

Comment: Thanks buddy. Its working fine. I waited for two days. I placed it in front of air blowing fan for two days and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked.